# Running Excel range.find method from Access vba module fails/error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, office365

Win10x64, office 365 x64
I am running an Access macro.
I'm opening an excel workbook, and then finding the last non-blank cell, or the first non-blank cell.
All constants are defined like this

```
xlPart = 2
xlFormulas = -4123
xlByRows = 1
xlNext = 1
```

`ws` is a Worksheet object.  I can select and activate the worksheet and a range without error e.g. these lines run fine

```
ws.Activate
ws.select
ws.Cells(1, 1).select
ws.Cells(1, 1).Activate
```

When I run this code I get a `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.` error

```
Set rFound = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(1, 1), _
                    xlPart, _
                    xlFormulas, _
                    xlByRows, _
                    xlNext, _
                    False)
```

But if i run this code, it works fine:

```
Set rFound = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(1, 1))
```

How can i pass the parameters from Access VBA to Excel Range.Find method.
**Please don't suggest other methods for finding non-blank cells**, I am doing that to complete this DB, but please try to answer the question on how making this particular method work from Access.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think the order of your parameters is wrong - this only matters when you're not using named parameters (as in your example).  I assume that's because you don't have a reference to Excel?

In any case have you checked the implicit order of the parameters to make sure you have them in the right order?

By default the order is defined as:

`expression.Find( What , After , LookIn , LookAt , SearchOrder , SearchDirection , MatchCase , MatchByte , SearchFormat )`

It looks like you have `LookIn` coming after `LookAt`

**Try changing it to:**

```
Set rFound = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(1, 1), _                        
                    xlFormulas, xlPart, _
                    xlByRows, xlNext, False)
```

[For reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)